# Smarty Remove Everything after specific character

Tags: smarty

I have this:

```
{$videos[i].videofile}
```

and my `$videos[i].videofile equals to  12931024123.mp4`

I want to remove everything after the dot. I have already tried `|strstr:'.':true`, but it does not work (wrong parameters count).

NO PHP NEEDED. Must be done with Smarty functions in the template.

Comment: I'm adding `php` tag(as `smarty` is for `php`), remove if not correct.

Comment: yeah, removed coz ppl started posting PHP solutions...

Comment: you mean that you want to output `12931024123`?

Comment: Yes bro, with or without dot.

Comment: If the file extension is always mp4, you can do it like this `{$videos[i].videofile|basename:'.mp4'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the cleanest solution but you asked specifically for it: you could simply use PHPs `substr` as a modifier:

```
{$videos[i].videofile|substr:0:-4}
```

This will return `12931024123`